# Escape variable for JavaScript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, escaping

I have the following code in asp.net:

```
string backToParentFunc = string.Format("backToParent('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}');",
                                              Server.UrlEncode(login),
                                              Server.UrlEncode(firstName),
                                              Server.UrlEncode(lastName),
                                              Server.UrlEncode(email);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "backToParent", backToParentFunc, true);
```

Of course it stops working when the "lastName" variable contains ['] symbol (O'Connell).
How to correctly escape strings in asp.net to make them appear correctly in JavaScript code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the `JavaScriptEncode` method from the [Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lastName.Replace("'", "\"").

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for a generic escaping method, not only for ['] symbol.

Comment: You have to escape the escape, \\' not just \'